# Series of Ajax request doesn't wait for finish

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, window.location

I have series of ajax calls, I want that when the calls get completed the page reloads , I am doing this

```
function verifyFrnds() {
    var boxes = $(".matchFrnds:checked").length;
    //alert(boxes);
    var call = 1;
    $(".matchFrnds").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            call++;
            var sendData = $(this).val();
            $.post('AJAX PAGE', {
                sendData: sendData
            }, function (data) {
                //window.location.reload();
            });
            //alert(call);
            //alert(call + ' ' + boxes + ' ' + (call >= boxes));
            if (call >= boxes) {
                // window.location.reload();
                alert("I am executed");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

so If I do alert, then all the ajax calls are exexuted and I am shown an alert message, but If I do `window.localtion.reload()` then after few ajax calls the page get reloaded, which should be reloaded after `ALL` calls. My main purpose is to reload the page when all calls are done.Any idea what I am doing wrong.
There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632753/jquery-ajax-page-reload) on SO but it didn't help me much.

Comment: jQuery`when` and `then`
http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Something to note -- Ajax calls are Asynchronous, which means they perform independently of any other process. This means that if you're looking to sequentially call Ajax, you'll have to use a callback

Answer (score 1):

Try using $.when:

```
function verifyFrnds() {
    var deferreds = []; //using an array to save promise interfaces
    $(".matchFrnds").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var sendData = this.value;
            //we push each request in array (returned promise interface)
            deferreds.push($.post('AJAX PAGE', {
                sendData: sendData
            }));
        }
    });
    //as $.when only accept deferred(promise) as arguments, we need to apply $.when to each promise of array
    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(function () {
        alert("I am executed once all requests done (success)");
        window.location.reload();
    });
}
```

Comment: Although this is the best solution to the problem it makes absolutely no sense without any explanation.

Comment: @A Wolff very strange behavious, sometime it execute all the ajax cals and some time execute very few..

Comment: Check your network tab for rejected requests (maybe too much parallel requests). Ideally, you should do only one request to server to send/retrieve all data at once.

Comment: @A.Wolff I checked the console and it actually didn't make the request,seems like the array is not filled with correct value..

Answer (score 0):

You could chain your ajax call using $.then if you need to do it sequentially. Like this:

```
function verifyFrnds() {
    var d = jQuery.Deferred();
    var p=d.promise();

    $(".matchFrnds:checked").each(function (index) {//instead of .matchFrnds
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            var sendData = $(this).val();
            p.then($.post('AJAX PAGE', {
                sendData: sendData
              }, function (data) {
                //window.location.reload();
              })
            );
        }
    });

    p.then(function(){
         alert("I am executed");
    });
    d.resolve();
}
```

Note that for jQuery prior to 1.8, you have to use .pipe instead of .then. Also check your code, I think there is a mistake, it should be `$(".matchFrnds:checked").each(` instead of  `$(".matchFrnds").each(`

Answer (score 0):

Just like *A. Wolff* said, use **jQuery.when** and **jQuery.then**.

Another alternative is: call a method on ajax finish ( jqXHR method **always** ) . Check if call >= boxes ( or whatever condition you like ) in that method. For me, this is a bit easy to understand as compared to another solution.

```
function verifyFrnds() {
    var boxes = $(".matchFrnds:checked").length;
    //alert(boxes);
    var call = 1;
    $(".matchFrnds").each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //call++; Move it to .always Thanks for pointing out Khanh
            var sendData = $(this).val();
            $.post('AJAX PAGE', {
                sendData: sendData
            }, function (data) {
                //window.location.reload();
            }).always ( function() {  
                // This method will be called on ajax completion. be it a failure or success.
                // see .done ( for success only )  ; .fail ( for failure only )
                call++;
                if (call >= boxes) {
                  // window.location.reload();
                   alert("I am executed");
                }
            }   ;


        }
    });
}
```

For more on jqXHR object. Read: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: same issue, it executed 7 calls out of 42 and reload the page

Comment: @user1765876: try putting `call++;` inside `.always` before `if (call >= boxes) {`

Comment: @user1765876: there is a mistake in the function. I think, It should be `$(".matchFrnds:checked").each` instead of `$(".matchFrnds").each`

Answer (score -1):

You should increment `call` not after the if, but in the success of your ajax calls.

I advice you to put the reload call in a function you call with setInterval and not in the success ajax returns.